# Gradle, Tika - Exclude some dependency packages making a "fat jar" too fat

Tags: java, gradle, executable-jar, apache-tika, build-dependencies

I'm making an app which creates Lucence indices on a handful of well-known document formats (.docx, .odt, .txt, etc.).

Tika is ideal for extracting the text but it appears to be the culprit in making my fat jar balloon to 62 MB.

To make the fat jar I'm doing this in my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies { // fatjar
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.4' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
shadowJar {
    baseName = project.name
    classifier = null
    version = project.version
}

task copyJarToBin(type: Copy) {
    from shadowJar
    into "D:/My Documents/Software projects/Operative/" + project.name
}
```

When I go `gradle dependencies`, Tika does indeed appear to have hundreds... most of them obviously I don't need.

Is there a known Gradle way of excluding/filtering out certain dependencies?

Specific to Tika: if anyone knows how to identify which dependencies handle which file types, that would be very useful too...

Comment: Might using the Tika 2.x branch be an option? The parser modules in 2.x are quite a bit more modular

Comment: Thanks... there's no mention of Tika 2 that I can see on the site: latest stable release from October last year is 1.14.  You seem to be an insider though: can you give me a link or tell me what's going on with that?

Comment: There's no official Tika 2.x release yet, as there are some other breaking API changes still to be made. The parser refactoring part is completed though. See https://wiki.apache.org/tika/Tika2_0RoadMap for details and links to grab the 2.x source code to build yourself

Comment: OK, thanks.  Do you have any tip or link to enable me to try to work out which dependencies I can safely exclude based on the filetypes I am and am not going to be covering (I mean for Tika 1.x or Tika 2.x)?

Comment: Review the parser modules available in 2, they generally have sensible names, compare those to the formats you want!

Comment: @Gagravarr Is this (the parser modules in Tika 2) still relevant? I see it hasn't been committed to since 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Gradle dependency management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html). You can exclude dependencies by module, group or both:

```
compile('library:with-a-lot-of-deps:1.0') {
    exclude module: 'weird-extension'
    exclude group: 'microsoft-extensions'
    exclude group: 'adobe-extensions', module: 'pdf-extension' 
}
```

And you can also remove dependencies from all configurations:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'all-the-unneeded-extensions'
}
```

No idea about Tika, but that would probably be a separate question anyway. Might be a good idea to read on Tika docs and inspect `META-INF` directory in the Jars.