# Use Gradle goodness to somehow extract and rebuild dependency jars?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, executable-jar

This follows on from this question: [Gradle, Tika - Exclude some dependency packages making a "fat jar" too fat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333087/gradle-tika-exclude-some-dependency-packages-making-a-fat-jar-too-fat)

The answer I chose there does indeed tell you how to cut down the size of a "fat jar" (i.e. an executable jar which contains all its dependencies within it) by stipulating which dependencies to exclude.

Using that technique I cut down my jar from 62 MB to 26 MB.  But extracting that jar and examining the volumes of the constituent directories (using a nifty app called [TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)) I find that my classes account for a mere 228 KB. The rest is dependencies.

Admittedly my project (or its dependencies) does use some powerful technologies: in particular Lucene (10 MB), Apache POI (10.5 MB), openxmlformats (10 MB) etc. (pre-compressed sizes, of course).

The thing is, I'm convinced that at any one time only a tiny fraction of the actual packages and classes contained in these individual dependent jars are actually used.

Given that a self-contained "fat jar" is not designed for versatility, so doesn't need to be congested with stuff it doesn't use, and given that Gradle is very clever and designed to do the heavy lifting for automating building, mightn't/shouldn't there be some way of extracting and packaging ONLY those classes that are actually needed: specifically by exploding the package jars and then repackaging only the classes needed?

26 MB isn't a huge size for a fat jar.  But the more "technologies" an individual project uses the bigger it will become by using only the coarse-grained technique of excluding dependency jars.

PS I'm aware this would be a far from trivial task!

Comment: I believe the intro to your question is not necessary. You should probably just start by posting the shadowJar configuration and ask how to remove certain files from it. Most people would not want to look at the other question to get the context. (I know it since I answered it :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use following approach to specify strictly what you want to see/not see inside your jar while still have it runnable

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependecies {
your dependencies
}   

jar {
    archiveName = 'Name.jar'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'uk.co.cdl.Main',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' '),
                'Implementation-Version': project.version
    }

    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
        exclude 'what you want to get rid dependencies/directories/files' etc
    }
}
```

With this solution by extending the jar task your gradle build will produce the runnable jar with libraries in the compile configuration needed to run.

PS. If you getting loads of transitive dependencies from your dependencies, try excluding them with

```
compile (artifactGrp:artifactId:version) {transitive=false}
```

PS2. There is a netflix plugin that I believe can scan through your gradle scripts a check unused dependencies 
https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin

PS3. There is a plugin that can scan the vulnerabilities of used dependencies etc
https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-gradle/

### Edit:

Your problem might be that you have not used correct configurations when feeding in dependencies its worth checking which dependencies should be `compile` which `compileOnly` and which `runtime` or `test` etc. or `provided...` after a proper config your app is gonna have exactly what you need and there will be no need of cutting it out later.

Comment: Thanks very much.  This is kind of over my head (as I thought any solution might be) with my current understanding of Gradle.  But it's also potentially fantastic, a good incentive for me to pick up a big thick book on Gradle and another on Groovy and start studying.

Comment: Um... I do indeed know about that and have answered quite a few times myself! Personally I don't necessarily expect people to upvote and/or accept immediately...

Comment: hi, @mikerodent it been a while now and I just thought about something it might be not relevant anymore but just got a +1 here and revisited the question I hope you have solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a Gradle plugin that does some kind of analysis of used and unused classes, but Gradle itself doesn't have such capability. It simply gathers dependencies that you have declared as needed and adds the transitive ones. ShadowJar plugin just unpacks them and packs them into a single jar.

Why is such task not trivial is because nobody can really know which classes are not used because the software you are using might use reflection to fetch the classes (it might use some kind of plugin mechanism, but likely the binding is done during runtime).

To do this manually, [you can filter the contents of the shadowJar](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#filtering_shadow_jar_contents):

```
shadowJar {
   exclude 'classes-you-dont-want.class'
}
```

Untested, but the plugin looks robust enough and probably will allow you to do things like:

```
shadowJar {
   exclude '**/*bad.class'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but doesn't really answer the question.  I'm not asking for manual removal of individual classes.  Incidentally, I'm not clear whether you are saying that individual classes (and packages?) can be removed from dependency jars using this technique... or just classes **in the current project**.  In any event, I want Gradle to do this ***automatically***: to work out which classes/packages in the dependency jars are used and only include those in the fat jar.

Comment: Having said that, thanks for finding that link... I believe the answer to my question is that I would have to use the mechanism in "Programmatically Selecting Dependencies to Filter" there and no doubt work this out by myself... once I have obtained a PhD in Gradle after about 10 years' hard study.

Comment: 'This follows on from this question: Gradle, Tika - Exclude some dependency packages making a "fat jar" too fat' - you should replace this intro with the configuration of the shadowJar. Self-contained questions have higher chance to be answered.

Comment: Yes, as I say I think the answer is "you'd have to do it yourself".  As for reflection, again this powerful Gradle module which is currently a figment of my imagination would have to be clever enough to ensure that reflection essentially wasn't used either by the app classes or the dependencies... at least if unknowable parameters were used.  Most of the dependency jars would presumably have to be extracted and their directory structures kept somewhere during development...